# how to pass data from a controller to several views asp.net mvc 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

hope the question isn't too wide range,
Basically, all I am seeking to do is take a figure(int) from a controllers ActionResult and pass that figure throughout my views.
I know it's something to do with adding the AllowAnonymous tag,
But should it be an ActionResult with a return view?
Also how would it be called in the views? something like ="@Url.Action("GetFigure")

Asp.ner MVC 4 application using razor2 views

Thanks guys

In my layout, which has no model or controller linked to it..

```
 <li class="@Html.ActiveTab("Mail")" id="mun2">
                <a href=@Url.Action("Index","Mail")>
                <i class="icon-envelope"></i> 
                <span class="badge badge-important">0</span>
                    <span class="title">Mails</span>
                    <span class="selected"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
```

ActionResult in Mail Controller

```
  [AllowAnonymous]
  public MailCount GetMailCount()
    {
        return new MailCount 
        {
            NewCount = _repo.GetAll().Where(x => x.Status.Equals((int)MialStatus.New)).Count(),

        };
    }
```

Comment: Can you post some code of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I undesrtand what you want, but if you just need to get some int value from Controller in View you may use ViewBag for this porpose:

In ControllerAction:

```
int figure = 2;
ViewBag.myfigure = figure;
```

in View:

```
@ViewBag.myfigure
```

If it is not what you want, then please explain your question in more details.

**EDITED:**
If you want to pass data to layout you may do it with PartialView:

In controller:

```
public ActionResult Menu()
{
  int figure = 2; //get your number of mails instead 2
  ViewBag.myfigure = figure;
  return PartialView();
}
```

in your Menu partial view:

```
<span>number of mails = @ViewBag.myfigure</span>
```

In your layourt:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Home")}
```

**EDITED 2**

In controller:

```
public ActionResult Menu()
{
  int figure = 2; //get your number of mails instead 2
  return PartialView(figure);
}
```

in your Menu partial view:

```
 @model int

<span>number of mails = @Model</span>
```

Comment: I might give that a go. I have a type of inbox, with list of mail, on the side menu I would like to display the number of new mail, but as the side menu is part of the layout view, I would need to get the Number in the mail controller and pass it to the layout view, does that explain it any better?

Comment: In your answer , that will only work if the controller is linked to the view ya? which in this case it's not..

Comment: Why don't you make the Menu Partial view typed on <int> ? ViewBag is evil!

Comment: @JanVanHerck yes, you are right. But I've started from ViewBag in my first answer. So I decided to continue my answer with it.

Comment: Legend !! the works lovely, is their much involved to change to an int ? as suggested?

Comment: If it's in the layout view, perhaps you could try using sub-actions?  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703541(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: @mkell yes you may change. One minute. I'll write

Comment: @mkell Done. You may try

Comment: perfect, there is no need for the @model int in the partial, thank you sir much appreciated...